# Go elastic client: have to wait some time before run query

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I use [olivere elastic library](http://github.com/olivere/elastic) to connect to elastic.
So I have one client, connect with it, add a few documents.
Then I have another client that make search. But I have to wait about seconds cause immediate response is empty

```
_, err := client.Index().
    Index(elasticTemplateName).
    Type(elasticType).
    Id(myID).
    BodyJson(myJson).
    Do(ctx)
require.NoError(t, err)

// wait cause of async elastic client
time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)

result, err := anotherClient.Search().Index(IndexName).SearchSource(searchSource).Do(ctx)
```

another client:

```
client, err := elastic.NewClient(
    elastic.SetURL(
        conf.Hosts...
    ),
    elastic.SetSniff(false),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the Refresh API see https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/release-branch.v6/indices_refresh.go

The insertion is real time but the indexes that the get uses are not

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- request immediate refresh
- wait until it is refreshed (scheduled refresh or another on-demand refresh)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the ES behaviour and has nothing to do with the GO client.

The ES doesn't index document immediately as they are added to the index (the default is every 1 second if I remember correctly). You can increase the index rate in the ES, and that would be good for development but in production and with high load on the ES that may result in degradation of the performance.

It is called the refresh_interval and you can read more about it in [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)